# image upload plugin to work with django admin and tiny MCE

Tags: django, tinymce

I'm looking for a way to upload images to a django `filefield` through a tiny mce plugin.

I've tried using IBrowser using [these](http://seoroot.com/blog/computing/programming/tinymce-ibrowser-plugin.html) instructions and figured I could then just write a python script in place of the php script that comes with the plugin.  But I can't even get the  button to display with those instructions, let alone rewrite it so that it works with django.

So I'm wondering if there is a well know way to create an upload image button that works with django and will upload to your server or if I can get ibrowser to work in this way.

Currently, tinymce is served to my django admin following [the django wikis](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor) suggestions. I've tried adding ibrowser with the following file structure:

```
-tinymce
    -plugins
        -ibrowser
            -editor_plugin.js
            -editor_plugin_src.js
            -...
```

but the button doesn't appear.

Again I'm all ears on how to get this to work with the ibrowser plugin or with a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`django-filebrowser`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-filebrowser/en/latest/) is an app that has tinymce support. You will also need to install `django-grappelli` as a requirement though which will significantly change the appearance of your admin